# Why globally declared variable is not accessible via window in Deno TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, deno

Why the `context` in example below is not accessible as the `window.context`?

It works fine for `get_context` function but not for the `context` variable, why?

Please note it's in **Deno TypeScript** setting.

[play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBzCB7ARlC8DeAoe8EIALvGCgHbEgAexAXPBQK4C2aIM+8AZsxWGIBLSkhIB9clVrEAFAEpGLdp1wBfXLikBnFEQB0qRLMQSp1OgvkEbNgPR34AdxQwA1tq2VdBo7KdCFMAoTvqmxJKUFnLy1g7Orh64AUEhYWZRMvAAvPAKOQB88ACMtgTxLu6eXhQ+IIYoxuYy1mXljpVJOnr1finBoc10cY4AojAwrsmBA-pDpLkATG228eOTXLi0AA6upNhqQA)

```
declare global {
  let context: number
  function get_context(): number
}

console.log(get_context())        // works
console.log(window.get_context()) // works
window.get_context = () => 1      // works

console.log(context)        // works
console.log(window.context) // Error
window.context = 2          // Error

export {}
```

Comment: `let` doesn't create properties on `window`.

Comment: @Ouroborus ha-ha, true, thanks, if changed to `var` it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `context` isn't block-scoped you need to declare it using `var` instead of `let`. You can also use `const` if you want it to be ready-only.

[Global Variables - Declaration Reference - TypeScript: Documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables):

> Use `declare var` to declare variables. If the variable is read-only, you can use `declare const`. You can also use `declare` let if the variable is block-scoped.